# Override a git repo

Tags: git, version-control

I have a local git repo that is not up to date with the remote repo. I don't want to pull changes, then push. The local repo should override the remote repo entirely. How do I do this with git?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the "override the remote repo" part ? Do you want to throw away your remote and replace it with a copy of the local ? or just do this for a specific branch ?

Answer (score 0):

***Be careful***.  Experiment with a couple throw away repositories before you try this with your real ones.  It's easy to screw things up and make it difficult to recovery the original state of your repository.

I think you're looking for `git push --mirror`.  The only catch here is that it will also push any remote references you have as well.

If you don't want that, then you need to setup a [refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-5.html) that works better for you (perhaps `+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` and `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`).  You can have more than one refspec line per remote.  I find it's easiest to go this by editing `.git/config`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a local `branch` which is out of sync with its remote counterpart, you can force the remote to update its branch to your state using the `-f` option :

```
push -f origin mybranch
```